# Active Directory Authentication Library Programmatic SSO

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, adfs, azure-ad-graph-api

We are using the ADAL C# library to acquire tokens to Azure AD Applciations (including the Graph API).

We have AD Connect set up with our Azure AD using an on premises ADFS 3.0 server. So, when a native client application calls....

```
var ourDomain = "abc.com";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + ourDomain;
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

var graphResourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net";
var azureADApplicationClientId = "7718c738-0000-0000-0000-4382476f1c65";

var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(
   graphResourceUri, 
   azureADApplicationClientId, new Uri("https://localhost"),
   PromptBehavior.RefreshSession, 
   new UserIdentifier($"jdoe@{ourDomain}", UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId), 
   $"domain_hint={ourDomain}");
```

An MSOnline login window pops up, immediately redirects to our ADFS server at

```
https://ouradfs.abc.com/adfs/ls/wia?username=.......................
```

And then immediately closes since NTLM (Windows Integrated) authentication occurs and succeeds...and `result` contains a valid access token for the logged in Windows user on our `abc.com` domain.

Although this process doesn't require any clicks...it is still "interactive". I'd like to be able to leverage Windows Integrated authentication to programmatically obtain such an access token in a non-interactive environment (such as a Windows Service or Scheduled Task). This way I wouldn't have to embed Client Secrets in our Windows Services or Scheduled Tasks.

Is this possible?

UPDATE: 
This is the line of code

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycorpdev.onmicrosoft.com");

AuthenticationResult result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(
  "https://graph.windows.net", 
  nativeApplicationClientId, 
  new Uri("https://localhost"),
  PromptBehavior.Never, 
  new UserIdentifier("jsmith@mycorp.com"), UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId), $"domain_hint=mycorp.com");
```

and the exact error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException occurred
  ErrorCode=user_interaction_required
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=user_interaction_required: One of two conditions was encountered: 1. The PromptBehavior.Never flag was passed, but the constraint could not be honored, because user interaction was required. 2. An error occurred during a silent web authentication that prevented the http authentication flow from completing in a short enough time frame
  Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask[T](Task`1 task)
```

ANOTHER UPDATE:

This works (where the client id and tenant are the same as the user's home tenant)

var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycorp.onmicrosoft.com");

```
AuthenticationResult result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(
  "https://graph.windows.net", 
  nativeApplicationClientIdFromHomeTenantNotOtherTenant, 
  new Uri("https://localhost"),
  PromptBehavior.Never, 
  new UserIdentifier("jsmith@mycorp.com"), UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId), $"domain_hint=mycorp.com");
```

UPDATE - Here is the capture from Fiddler

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycorpdev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&client_id=78ebfdee-8144-48f8-9a96-1bd5418c0492&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&login_hint=jsmith%40mycorp.COM&client-request-id=7a8878d4-2762-4784-9d29-6f49b147d474&prompt=attempt_none&x-client-SKU=.NET&x-client-Ver=2.19.0.0&x-client-CPU=x64&x-client-OS=Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.1.7601+Service+Pack+1&domain_hint=mycorpdev.onmicrosoft.com HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT=AAABAAEAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLfZQz8hXb5bXR-iThmkV-FLuLx102LOLAWrogj3rvf40Xl0xjZntMo0Kzvbo0x38Z2CpfCjtOwyyVpp1DWlxyyRPBbl4Z4da5pFuYjfCLPqExGUvo5gBoMdeQ-0MobfbSV2GQCHgbL1CFRjOu6YJZUEgnk7Vyls4rOlHGaqEGpzm5OeFQj3acldcvD9C4PX1gGsV-2g5GU8Frx3co4YzqYHMbhp6fgzf18sfgWaaG9caWj756P2oDvqe9qAlehXk51cA2AUacM2h-k2rtN8F341p7tnOFkNBzCj_E4z3bTnwHodimoXLiDlDWjFWkzAANyAA


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Location: https://localhost/?error=login_required&error_description=AADSTS50058%3a+User+account+identifier+is+not+provided.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+133f0405-eb3d-452d-a8b6-b6ba6267af7c%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+7a8878d4-2762-4784-9d29-6f49b147d474%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2016-02-21+04%3a54%3a07Z
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-ms-request-id: 133f0405-eb3d-452d-a8b6-b6ba6267af7c
client-request-id: 7a8878d4-2762-4784-9d29-6f49b147d474
x-ms-gateway-service-instanceid: ESTSFE_IN_420
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
Set-Cookie: flight-uxoptin=true; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=productionb; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 21 Feb 2016 04:54:05 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

One more update...

If I try to use integrated auth (note it DOES try to redirect to our ADFS correctly...):

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(""https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName.Split('@')[1]), false);
var nativeClientId = "00000000-0f32-4c38-bdb9-4ea5bd732c69";
var token = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.ReportingApplicationUri, nativeClientId, new UserCredential()).Result;

System.AggregateException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
:line 68
  InnerException: 
       ErrorCode=federated_service_returned_error
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Federated service at https://ds1.mycorp.com/adfs/services/trust/2005/windowstransport returned error: The message with Action 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
       Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
       StatusCode=500
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WsTrustRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenNonInteractiveHandler.<PreTokenRequest>d__4.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
              --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpWebRequestWrapper.<GetResponseSyncOrAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
              --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WsTrustRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can do it in 2 alternative ways.

1. Pass `PromptBehavior.Never`. That will use an invisible browser, making the operation 100% non interactive. This works both with Kerberos and with any other session type (eg cookies).
2. Use the `AcquireToken` overload which accepts a `UserCredential`. Pass to it an empty `UserCredential`, as in `new UserCredential()`. That will force the use of Kerberos authentication.

Comment: 1 - Not as far as I can tell. Never actually seems to only work if the token is in the ADAL TokenCache, otherwise fails.

Comment: Regarding 2 - what if the account name is currently tied to more than one Azure AD? Is there a way to bypass that screen where it asks if you want to use a "Work Account" or a "Microsoft Account"

Comment: That should not be the case. The behavior you described applies to AcquireTokenSilent, as it only looks at the cage, but the invisible browser in PromptBehavior.Never should do the job. Can you grab a fiddler trace and see what happens on the wire? Also, did you try #2?

Comment: Regarding 2, as it uses Kerberos there are no screens at all. The tenant is determined by the authority you are passing. If your user is a guest from another tenant, then this won't work as you need interactivity for specifying a username from a tenant other than the one specified in the authority

Comment: It looks like it's bombing because of the exact scenario I asked about for number 2. The clientid is from testabc.com tenant, but the user is from the abc.com tenant, added as an external user to testabc.com. Is there any way to handle that scenario?

Comment: Then #2 isn't an option. However #1 should work, you just need to specify abc.com (the home tenant of the user) as domain_hint in the extraqueryparameters.

Comment: Updated question....maybe has to do with having both a MS account and an Azure AD account with the email jsmith@mycorp.com

Comment: That is very possible - it is altogether a different problem than federated guests backed by an ADFS. The plot thickens! Is there any chance of testing that flow with a user that does NOT have an MSA associated with it?

Comment: Also, that is definitely a non trivial piece of information. I would recommend adding it to the the question as well, as it might make the difference between feasibility or impossibility with today's features

Comment: it works if my authority/client id belong to the home tenant of jsmith btw

Comment: That's because there is only one level in that case. The difficulty here hinges on disambiguation- you need to pick a different tenant than the one used for issuing, you need to distinguish between an org user and an MSA, and you need to identify an ADFS all in the same call given that you don't want interactivity. We have mechanisms for solving guest and ADFS resolution, but I have doubts about the org/MSA disambiguation without interaction.

Comment: the domain_hint doesn't do the trick? Is there another query string parameter I could pass instead?

Comment: The domain_hint identifies the tenant from which the user is supposed to be from - but i am not sure if it takes precedence in respect to the fact that the user is ALSO an MSA. I would really need to see the fiddler trace to be able to say more - or we can sit until Monday and I can ask people at the office (tho I suspect the request for a trace won't go away)

Comment: I can get you a fiddler trace - which EXACT request do you want to see?

Comment: The entire traffic that starts from the call to acquiretoken and leads to the error. Note that I might still not be able to look into it until Monday, the wife is yelling at me :)

Comment: Why would she be yelling at you for working on a Saturday night at 11PM? haha

Comment: Remember that "invisible browser"? Well, if I try to Fiddler it with it set to Never, I get the error above

Comment: in your fiddler trace the domain of the user's UPN and the domain in the domain_hint are different. is myCORP.com a registered domain? Can you try using it in the domain_hint?

Comment: Awesome!! So if I use the mycorpdev tenant as the authority and the clientid from a mycorpdev app, but the domain_hint is mycorp, I can AcquireToken with PromptBehavior.Never. My only question is - will this work from a Windows Service with a non-interactive session? Or an IIS app pool?

Comment: Ah good, I am so glad it finally works :) I think the usual restrictions to services apply. You might need to allow the service to perform interactive logon, although I have to admit it's been few years hence I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Does the new UserCredential() approach also do a hidden browser redirect? Or something different?

Comment: As I said earlier, it uses a different approach. It won't work with guests, it is viable only if the user is native to the same tenant that is expected to issue the token.

Comment: I tried with the native tenant as well and got the exception I pasted at the bottom of my post

Comment: that usually indicates an issue with the ADFS setup, or with the ADAL version. Make sure that your ADFS has Kerberos over wstrust enabled and that you have the absolute latest nuget for ADAL (2.x if you are targeting production, 3.x if you are experimenting with the preview)

Comment: I see. I can see its trying to use ntlm. That's not supported?

Comment: It should be. The main issue here is on the mex endpoint, hence the comment on ADFS setup or ADAL version. It looks like this discussion is stretching a bit. Givne that the main point of the question has been addressed, I'd recommend starting a new question if you want to dig deeper on specific aspects